# TensorFlow: How to feed a dataset that doesn't fit into memory?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

[`DataSet` documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) claims that it `Represents a potentially large set of elements.` as well as `Iteration happens in a streaming fashion, so the full dataset does not need to fit into memory.`.

I spent several hours in the [official docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data) trying to find out how to feed a large dataset in a streaming fashion. No success. All examples use either `from_tensor_slices` or generator, both methods are not recommended by TensorFlow themselves because of `2GB limit for the tf.GraphDef protocol buffer` and  `it has limited portability and scalability. It must run in the same python process that created the generator, and is still subject to the Python GIL.`.

The only documented way I found to make it work in a streaming fashion is [to use `TFRecord`](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tfrecord). It allows to stream file by file. The only huge problem: my feature input shape is `(200000, 2)` (all float32). To flatten and convert it to `FloatList` is not an option because I feed it to Conv1D with 2 parallel sequences.

It feels like either I overlooked something, or it's just poorly documented, or `tf.Dataset` doesn't do what it claims to do.

Is there a way to make DataSet work in a streaming fashion for a large set of elements?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Yes, the recommended way to stream data from disk is using TFRecords (there are also `TextLineDataset` and `FixedLengthRecordDataset` but TFRecords are preferred). But even if you put each data example in a `FloatList`, you can retrieve them later with any shape you need. You usually specify it with [`tf.io.FixedLenFeature`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/FixedLenFeature), but even if the retrieved data was "flattened" you would just need to reshape it.

Comment: retrieve them later with any shape you need - you mean a lambda layer? Hmm, sounds like an additional overhead. I'd like to avoid any additional conversion if possible

Comment: There is actually no overhead in reshaping a tensor (unless you reorder its axes). But I don't mean that, I mean for example if `dataset` is your `TFRecordDataset`, do `dataset.map(lambda rec: tf.io.parse_single_example(rec, {'data': tf.io.FixedLenFeature(shape=(200_000, 2), tf.float32)})['data'])` (assuming you only want to retrieve that `data` value from your record, though you probably also want a label or something else) - in actual code, however, do not directly pass a `lambda` to `.map`, it works but it will complain it cannot make it into a `tf.function`...

Comment: I see, thank you @jdehesa ! One more question: how do you handle memory limits? E.g. I have N thousands of 100 MB `TFRecord` files. Should I feed all those files into `TFRecordDataset` at once and it will balance the memory load, or do I have to handle it myself in an outer loop feeding only e.g. 10 files per dataset and then create a dataset again (hence training for 1 epoch again every 10 next files)?

Comment: If you're concerned about scalability and performance, you may have a look at [this guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance). For your case, you could for example have something like `tf.data.Dataset.list_file('data/*.tfrecord').cache().shuffle(10_000)` and then call [`interleave`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#interleave), then maybe `shuffle` again and then `map` with the parsing function and end with `.repeat().prefetch()`.